# Get members that belongs to team

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get all members that is in the same teams as the user which is logged in.

Table examples:

team table:

```
id     name
1      Test team
2      Second team
```

member table:

```
uid     team_id
4       1
10      2
1       2
```

The logged in user have uid = 4.

In this example, it should only return 1 user, because the logged in user (uid = 4) only belongs to 1 team.

This is the code I've at the moment, but it's taking all the user (whether they are a part of the same team or not)

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('teams');
$this->db->join('members', 'members.team_id = teams.id');
$this->db->join('users', 'members.uid = users.id');
$this->db->group_by('uid');
```

Hope someone have any inputs of how to fix this :-)

Comment: You don't have a where clause for the logged-in user

Comment: It should also take the members which is a part of the team I'm a part of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but I'm guessing you want to get all the members from the team the logged in user is part of. In that case try:

```
$user_id = 4 or  $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT team_id FROM members WHERE uid = $user_id) tid
        JOIN members m ON m.team_id = tid.team_id
        LEFT JOIN team_table tt ON tt.id = m.team_id
        GROUP BY m.uid";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

here we go again:

```
SELECT * 
FROM member
WHERE team_id=(SELECT team_id FROM member WHERE uid=4)
```

see [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5629/7)

Comment: It does only takes myself and not the other members which is a part of the team I'm a part of :-)

Comment: It should only show you, since you the only member of team id 4; team id 2 will have 2 members

Comment: Yes, but if I add my uid to the members table to team 2, it only shows me also, because of the "where member.uid=4" - it should show all the members which is a part of the same teams as I am